# Get a text from a php variable (URL)

Tags: php, php4

i have a php variable `$link="http://localhost/mysite/?product=men-glasses1"`, and I would like to display only the test after the "=" , that is here `men-glasses1`.
Can someone help?.

Comment: Use `strpos` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php and `substr`http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and then show us what you tried.

Comment: Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to return params section then [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert it into an associative array

```
$link="http://localhost/mysite/?product=men-glasses1";
parse_str( parse_url( $link, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $output );

echo $output["product"];
// men-glasses1
```

see this [**demo**](https://eval.in/179890)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strstr` and `substr`:

```
echo substr(strstr($link, "="),1);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strstr.php
http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in this case:

```
$var = explode('=',$link);
echo $var[1]; //men-glasses1
```

or if it's just in stage of URL (not in a variable yet), then you can just simply access it this way:

```
$_GET['product'];
```

Or as your link may get more and more sophisticated you may have a look at regular expressions. I would recommend using [this tool](http://www.txt2re.com) to generate your regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strstr()` function in php to do this.This function searches for the first occurrence of a string inside another string Your code should look like this

```
    <?php
$link="http://localhost/mysite/?product=men-glasses1";
    echo strstr($link, "=");
    ?>
```

Hope this helps you